# Getting error 'This page includes from unauthenticated sources'

Tags: javascript

I am new to salesforce.I have added some css classes to my vf page, but when I open my vf page it says "This page includes from unauthenticated sources".
I need to click on "Load unsafe script" then my css work.
Please advice.

Comment: Is your page pointing to or including a non https// page/reference?